# Simple way to position window at center (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

In a big display, with high resolution, there is a need to take a window that takes 50% of desktop and position it in the center.
In Windows 10 (and some previous versions) there is a shortcut WIN  + Arrow left/right to take up to 50% of space but it also puts window by a side.

What I would like to find a solution for is a shortcut to make similar action but instead of placing application window to the left or the right side put is right in the center

An example of a monitor in which such shortcut is disirable:
[image]

Comment: While it will not center it, `Windows Key` + `Down Arrow Key` will set the window back to the size and position it was at before any form of snap.  If you position it before snapping full screen, you can use that shortcut to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Answered on [so], [How can a batch file run a program and set the position and size of the window?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10392620)

Comment: Not quite sure why this was closed as off-topic when the reason given doesn't seem to relate to this question in any way...

Comment: Install AltTab software, configure Button 4 (and 5?) as "center a window". Then Alt-Key4 centers it, and drag top bar up make it vertikally full screen.

Comment: @radzimir Could you share a link to the software you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, it was AltDrag: https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/